# If $A=c+d, B=ci-di$, what allows me to say that the values of $A,B$ are independent of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If $A=c+d, B=(c-d)i$, what allows me to say that the values of $A,B$ are independent of each other?

This comes from simplifying the constants of the solutions of a second order homogeneuos differential equation with complex roots of it's characteristic polynomial.

E:
$$y''+ay'+by=0$$

If the characteristic equation has roots $\lambda=\nu\pm \xi i$ then the solutions are given by: 
$$y=c e^{(\nu + \xi i)x}+d e^{(\nu - \xi i)x}$$

Operating for a while we end up with

$$y = e^{\nu x}((c+d)\cos (\xi x)+(ci-di)\sin(\xi x))$$

And we express this as:

$$y = e^{\nu x}(A\cos (\xi x)+B\sin(\xi x))$$

Comment: Can you add the details of your derivation in the ODE. :) I don't think there is such a need to this! Also, what causes you to say $A$ and $B$ are not independent?

Comment: Added the derivation, @H.R. . I wonder why this renaming doesn't cause a loss of the information given by the relationships of $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a day I thought like you but this is not what is really happening! :)

> **Theorem**. Consider the differential equation $y''+ay'+by=0$ where $a$ an $b$ are some **real** constants. The **real** and **imaginary** parts of the complex valued function $f(x)$ of real variable $x$ defined on $(-\infty +\infty)$ by the equation $f(x)=e^{tx}$ are the solutions of this differential equation if and only if $t$ is a root of the characteristic equation $t^2+at+b=0$.

According to this theorem, we do not play with constant! We take the real and imaginary parts of some **complex valued function of real variable**. In fact our solution is

$$y(x)=A\, \Re(f(x)) + B\, \Im(f(x))$$

where $A$ and $B$ are some real constants. If we think like you, $A$ and $B$ should be complex constants which is **not** consistent with $y(x)$ being a real valued function! :)

Comment: Ah, that's true. I remember reading that in some book about systems of linear differential equations, it turns out that $\{\Re(f),\Im(f)\}$ are L.I., making a good basis the solutions of a real valued functions, right? 

This makes me think that the explanation I posted (given in most more 'basic' ode courses) is more of an heuristic argument, rather than a rigorous proof, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Yeah! you are right! :) of course, you can prove this theorem easily by yourself. I don't know that why they put some bad ideas in the student's mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could say that if you write $A = c + d$ and $B = c - d$ then you have
$A = B + 2d$, but if $d$ is arbitrary then $A$ and $B$ are independent, since if $B$ has a particular value $A$ can still be any other value.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the question, $B=(c-d)i$.